# SSH X11 forwarding only works when using trusted

Tags: ssh, x11

When I try to use X11 forwarding, I am getting the error, "cannot open display" message.

If I use trusted X11 forwarding "-Y", then it works as expected.  I can use x2go without any issues.  My ssh_config and sshd_config both permit X11 Forwarding (both on remote server and on local client).

Additionally, I even allowed X access from all clients via xhost +.  When remoting into my box (without -Y), I see the DISPLAY env variable is unset.  When remoting into my box (with -Y), I see the DISPLAY env variable is set.  If I merely try to set the DISPLAY env variable (even when  not using -Y), that has no effect.

I believe I should not be using trusted X11 forwarding as there is a slight security risk by doing so (even though it works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is broken as per gentoo bug:
https://bugs.gentoo.org/237778
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-842298-start-0.html

Answer (score -1):

Launching apps over X11 can be really slow. I recommend tunneling VNC over SSH.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/tunneling-vnc-connections-over-ssh-howto.html

Comment: This is not what I'm asking.

Comment: Follow your bliss.  I've used VNC tunneled over SSH on 100+ customer systems all over the world without a problem, and I've seen GUIs run over X11 forwarding work very, very slowly.